# Counting substrings in a string

Tags: c, string, count

I have the task to make a little program with pointers and I am facing a problem with `const char*s`. The program is meant to count the number of times that a sub-string appears in a main-string. Also, the different positions, where the sub-strings start, should be saved in a char** ptr. This is my little testing code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    int i=-1;
    int k=0;
    char** ptr;
    char* str="cucumber";
    char* substr="cu";

    while(strstr(str, substr)!=NULL)
        {
            i++;
            ptr[i]=strstr(str, substr);
            str = strpbrk(str, substr)+1;
            k++;
        }

    printf("%i",k);
}
```

It should print 2, since the sub-string 'cu' appears 2 times in 'cucumber' - yet, my compiler tells me that I am using chars, when I should use constant ones. Except, I don't know how to do that.

The strstr() function requires them. What should I change?

Comment: execution of this program (if it would compile) will cause undefined behaviour because setting ptr[x] will try to write to a ptr array, however, ptr is declared as a single pointer, not as an array.

Comment: Dude you are writing to unallocated memory. You have not allocated memory for char** ptr;

Comment: Homework problem again!!

Comment: @siu And? The context in which the question is asked is irrelevant for Stack Overflow. We only care about how well-formed and clear the question is. In this case it is clear what the task is, what the problem is, and the work so far is posted. So it is a pretty decent question. It just needs less smilies.

Answer (score 0):

```
// note:
// 1) correction to declaration of main()
// 2) addition of return statement
// 3) 'substr' is a poor name choice for a variable, as 
//    a) it looks like a C lib function (it is a ACL library function)
//    b) it does not clearly convey what the variable contains
// 4) clutter in the 'while' loop removed
// 5) 'while' loop is replaced by a 'for' loop so more can be accomplished with less code 
// 6) unneeded variables are eliminated
// 7) the 'for' loop stops when there is no possibility of further testStr occurrences
// 8) the printf() clearly indicates what is being printed



#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char* testStr="cucumber";
    char* findStr="cu";
    int k = 0;

    for( int i=0; strlen(&testStr[i]) >= strlen(findStr); i++)
    {
        if( strstr(&testStr[i], findStr) != NULL)
        {
            k++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nnumber of occurrences of %s in %s is %d\n", findStr, testStr, k);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: This code is very inefficient. All those repeated calls to strlen aren't necessary.

Comment: thanks for your efforts =) I still have some trouble understanding: How is the strlength relevant and furthermore: won't the strlen of the testStr always be higher than the findStr? The for loop wouldn't end, would it?

Comment: Also, my compiler says "[Error] 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode"

Answer (score 0):

Allocate memory for storing the pointer values

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SUB_STR 10
int main()
{
    int i;
    int k;
    char* ptr[MAX_SUB_STR];
    char* str="cucumber";
    char* temp;
    char* substr="cu";

    i = 0;
    k = 0;
    temp = str;
    while(strstr(temp, substr)!=NULL && k < MAX_SUB_STR)
        {
            ptr[k]=strstr(temp, substr);
            temp = ptr[k] + strlen(substr);
            k++;
        }

    printf("%i\n",k);
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
        printf("%p\n",ptr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```